# Jmeter Groovy Assert Keyword is not Causing Assertion Failure in Tree View Listener

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, jsr223, jmeter-3.2

Is it possible to get assertion failed in tree view listener using this line of code in JSR223 Assertion?

```
assert 1 == 2
```

Before in JMeter version 3.1 i could do this without any problem and now its just not working. I know i can use these lines of code

```
if(1 != 2) {
AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('They are not equal') }
```

but i would, if possible, like to keep it simpler and shorter like before, with just one line of code

Comment: what happens when you use `assert` statement? Isn't it shown?

Comment: It is not shown in Tree View Listener, but only in log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using assert will be possible in next 4.0 version as per:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61534

You can try jmeter nighlty build:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

I don’t think it was possible to do that in 3.1

Comment: Thank you UBIK LOAD PACK, this is the answer i was looking for. By the way it was working in 3.1 version, i can confirm this. I have all three versions opened and run same code, in 3.1 its working in 3.2 and 3.3 its not working

Answer (score 0):

I do confirm it is possible to use the above code for failing a sampler in JMeter 3.3 (latest version as of now)

[image: JMeter 3.3 Groovy Response Assertion]

Make sure that:

1. The sampler you want to fail is located somewhere in the [Assertion Scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)
2. You have [groovy-all.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. There are no any suspicious entries in *jmeter.log* file

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for your reply but it didnt answer the question. I know using IF and AssertionResult i can get code failing, but is it possible to do it with only one line of code like before and that is **assert 1 == 2** ?

Comment: Using groovy [assert keyword](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html#_power_assertions) won't fail your sampler, the only thing you will get is the message in *jmeter.log* file, if you're looking for a simplified "one line" solution for whatever reason use something like `if (1 != 2) throw new Exception('They are not equal')`. More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, i really appreciate your answer, i will use the way of writhing it that you showed until 4.0 version when hopefully jmeter will be back on simple assert keyword